# Terminal window writes black block in output after mutt return

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal, mutt

I just recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (running Gnome Flashback-Metacity, if that matters) and whenever I run mutt in Terminal, there is a black box that appears after the exit output mutt provides:
[image]
This does not happen with another interactive command such as vi nor a command that returns output such as grep.

I've tried a variety of settings changes on the default profile with no effect, unless I change to having white text on black background.  Here are the current colors settings:
[image]
Anyone have hints as to where I should be looking to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: As it can be seen, your gnome-terminal is running with a "black on white" color scheme. I assume your mutt has a "white on black"-ish scheme, am I right? What happens when you try other terminal emulators (e.g. xterm, konsole, urxvt) with similar "black on white"-ish color schemes?

Comment: Thanks!  xterm -rv (to get the white-on-black instead of the default xterm black-on-white) doesn't cause the above problem.  In both cases whether I run mutt in gnome-terminal or xterm -rv, the mutt session is also white-on-black.

Comment: If I specify foreground and background colors explicitly to be black-on-white, instead of using `-rv`, the above gnome-terminal problem also happens in xterm.  My .muttrc uses `color normal default default` as its color specification.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a bug in ncurses provided in Ubuntu 16.04.  Here's the bug ticket explaining the issue and workaround (which I summarize below):  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutt/+bug/1582629

The workaround is to add the `color normal default default` line right above the `source /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d` line in /etc/Muttrc (which is the last line in that file).  You'll need administrator privileges to do so.

The issue is fixed for Ubuntu 16.10, so if you're willing to leave the LTS version you won't have to do this workaround.  Thanks @egmont for your help!